How to remove a linux partition and extend it back to the adjacent hard disk from a dual boot windows 10 and ubuntu (latest release 24.04 LTS) setup?
I tried installing linux ubuntu 24.04 LTS as a second OS on my system and didn't really partition a good amount of data (recommended 25gb of data) instead I partitioned only about 7gb which is not sufficient. Now I just want to go back to windows 10 and not have linux ubuntu anymore. I've put windows to the top of my boot options so that grub bootup screen won't show up and that works well.
Only thing now is I want to delete the partition I had done for linux ubuntu and join it back to the hard disk. I tried using disk management tool from windows but it doesn't show any option "Delete Volume" on the linux partition. I even tried diskpart.exe but when deleting using delete partition override it shows this:
DISKPART> delete partition override

Virtual Disk Service error:
The operation is not supported by the object.

The specified command or parameters are not supported on this system.

I'm really frustrated at this point and need help from someone experienced in this. Is there any other way to fix this issue?
The linux partition is the one which is on disk 0 and is 7.48gb (Primary Partition)
Here is my disk management tool screen:
Disk management

Does this answer your question? How to resize partitions?

I don't think you can do what you want to do from within Windows -- because you would be joining the old Ubuntu partition with a running, mounted Windows partition.
I think what you have to do is create an Ubuntu boot disk on a USB drive.  Start Ubuntu from that so that neither the Windows drive nor the Ubuntu 7 GB partition are mounted.
Start from that and obviously don't choose the "Install" option.  Choose the "Try Ubuntu" option and run gparted.  There are other programs, but this is the most graphical and (IMHO) easiest to use.  If it isn't part of the USB drive, then just install it (sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install gparted).  I think running it is self explanatory -- first delete the Ubuntu partition and then extend the Windows one.  If everything for the Windows drive is greyed out, then you might have to also install the ntfs-3g package to enable NTFS support.
When you're done, you can reboot.  When that is all done, you probably want to remove grub.  I guess you can look at past questions here on how to do that (it's a separate task that I would suggest you do last).
Whatever you do, if you do it wrong, then you can use Boot Repair to fix it.
Hope this helps!

I fixed my problem on windows by erasing data in the partition and then extending the HDD to the deleted partition using some software. It was risky cause i couldn't make a backup for my hdd that has a lot of large files in it, but then just trusted my gut and got it to normal.

@Anonymous21 Good to hear you solved your problem!  Indeed, it is risky and the safest thing to do is to make a backup before hand.
